# ODI date format

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-data-integrator

I am trying to resolve a date from a flat file, but I haven't been successful with setting the right date format. Do you have any idea what's wrong with this one?

```
ODI-40469: Value was incorrect for column 0: Could not transform "2021-04-30T00:00:00Z" to date using pattern yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z' at position 1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've probably fixed this by now but anyhow... The `HH:mm:ss` should be `HH24:mi:ss` for starters.

Additionally, as a query, I had to use double quotes for T and Z rather than single quotes as per below:

`select to_date('2021-04-30T00:00:00Z','yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss"Z"') as my_date from dual;`